# Routing issues in regex codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

Problem is i have two routes

$route['management/(:any)']         = 'mycontroller/home/$1';
$route['management/(:any)/contact'] = 'mycontroller/contact/$1';

First route is working properly but second is not working. can any one please guide me
i am using codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the order in which you write them. The first one is probably catching that route, so it's never making it to the second one.